# What type of scattering happens, when the "free" electrons in conductor receive the em wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, electrons

We know for sure, that antennas(depending on their parameters), or just simple wires can receive(and emit) a large spectrum frequencies of em waves(from 1 Hz to 300 GHz for sure). But to excite an atom there's only one discrete energy, and anothers, as I understood, will be transparent for atom. How then antennas receive em waves?

Answer (score 1):

Conductors are modeled with the [band theory of solids](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/band.html). The conduction band electrons  belong to the whole lattice of atoms. Even though they are bound at an energy level with respect to the lattice, the difference in energy levels is so small that one can model it as a continuum. Electrons can transfer within the band by interacting with a photon of very small energy. Look [at the spectrum,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Electromagnetic_spectrum) the 300 gigaherz are mili evs. So in conductors these  photon energies can be easily absorbed within the conduction band electrons.

Now how the photons build up the classical electromagnetic wave is another story, and if you have the rudiments of quantum field theory have a look [here.](https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html)